# How to update Microsoft.AspNetCore?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am running 2.1.0-rc1-final but I noticed that 2.1.1 is now out. I am wondering how to update my code?

When I try to update it in the nuget ui manager it says "blocked by project"

Comment: Have you installed dotnet sdk 2.1.300?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928947/netcore-2-1-1-release-leads-to-failing-build/50929722

Answer (score 4):

Make sour you have a recent version of the .NET Core SDK installed (currently 2.1.301) and no explicit version set for the metapackage you are using:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
…
  <ItemGroup>
    <!--  No Version needed -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. `dotnet --version` shows `2.1.402` but `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package is stuck at `2.1.1` and later stable versions (`2.1.2` through `2.1.4`) are all blocked.

Comment: @Isaac that's not a problem, that's by design. You don't need to update this package.

Comment: @MartinUllrich, thank you for you comment. Could you explain what do you mean when saying "that's by desing"? I am experiencing the same issue as @Isaac and I don't understand why Microsoft is releasing new versions of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App that I cannot/"don't need" to use even if the last asp.net core SDK and runtimes are installed on my laptop. In my case `dotnet --version` shows 2.1.403 fro the SDK and 2.1.5 for the runtime. Thanks

Comment: any app built for the `.app` package <= 2.1.5 will run on the 2.1.5 runtime if it is installed. if you install a newer version, say 2.1.6, it will automatically use this one. there is no need to update the NuGet Package unless you specifically don't want an app to run on a version lower than the one selected.

Comment: @MartinUllrich: Thats not true in my case. I have the latest SDK-Version installed (2.2.104) and even if Version 2.2.2 is available, my Project swichtes over to 2.2.0 after removing the Version from .csproj.

Comment: @Joshit: that's expected for 2.2.0. All framework dependent apps should build for 2.2.0 as they will roll forward to the highest available patch version of the runtime that is installed.  `2.1.1` was special since it fixed some build process bugs which is why this answer exists in the first place. When you do a self-contained publish (e.g. `dotnet publish -r win-x64`) it will switch to the new version automatically