# Netcore 2.1.1 release leads to app failing to run

Tags: asp.net-core

It seems there is suddenly something out of sync with asp.net core packages.

It looks like [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/) was released 16 hours ago on nuget.org but only 158 downloads, and apparently I'm one of the downloaders.

My `.csproj` file is like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\cloudscribe.Web.Navigation\cloudscribe.Web.Navigation.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\cloudscribe.Web.SiteMap\cloudscribe.Web.SiteMap.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\cloudscribe.Web.SiteMap.FromNavigation\cloudscribe.Web.SiteMap.FromNavigation.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

It builds but when I try to run it I get:

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
>   The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.1' was not found.
>     - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>         C:\Program Files\dotnet\
>     - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
>         http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
>     - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
>         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
>     - The following versions are installed:
>         2.1.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

If I change my version for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App to 2.1.0 and do dotnet restore I get this:

> C:_c\cloudscribe.Web.Navigation\src\NavigationDemo.Web\NavigationDemo.Web.csproj : error NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue.
>   C:_c\cloudscribe.Web.Navigation\src\NavigationDemo.Web\NavigationDemo.Web.csproj : error NU1107:  NavigationDemo.Web -> cloudscribe.Web.Navigation -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (>= 2.1.1)
>   C:_c\cloudscribe.Web.Navigation\src\NavigationDemo.Web\NavigationDemo.Web.csproj : error NU1107:  NavigationDemo.Web -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (= 2.1.0).
>     Restore failed in 3.54 sec for C:_c\cloudscribe.Web.Navigation\src\NavigationDemo.Web\NavigationDemo.Web.csproj.

I suppose that is partly due to the other projects in my solution with dependencies like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" Version="2.1.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="2.1.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="2.1.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.1.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="2.1.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" Version="2.1.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.1.*" />
```

There does not seem to be an updated sdk for `2.1.1` but the availability of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1` on GitHub seems to be breaking things for me.

Comment: for the moment I can solve the problem by pinning all my packaged deps to 2.1.0 and close solution and delete the bin and obj folders. Then after re-opening my solution it builds and runs. As @khellang mentioned on gitter, maybe the 2.1.1 release is still in progress and not all ready yet.

Comment: Nuget usually takes some time until the cache is updated and a new verision of a specific package is visible on Nuget, that may be causing the issue. What may help is to install the latest SDK which should contain the latest ASP.NET Core installed in the local package cache (which is then located in C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App and C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder respectively and used as fallback by nuget)

Comment: @Tseng I think the problem may be because they haven't yet shipped a new sdk since the 2.1.0 release. The downloads don't show a new sdk version yet.

Comment: It is failing because you don;t have a matching SDK installed. Unfortunately Microsoft release the Nuget packages before the SDK installer so you either have to target a specific framework version or be patient and wait for the SDK.

Comment: Probably you need to wait until the .NET Core SDK 2.1.1 is available which u can find [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows ).
If u can't wait, check out the [early access](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/.NET-Core-2.1.1-Early-Access-Downloads).

Comment: my lesson learned is it that while it is ok to use wildcard for patch versions of my own libraries, since I control them and know that patch versions won't have breaking changes, it is best to pin to specific versions of Microsoft and 3rd party libraries. Probably a new sdk is needed to use the 2.1.1 Microsoft libraries, but I would not have suddenly found my builds breaking this morning if I had been pinned to 2.1.0 instead of using 2.1.*

Comment: @JoeAudette See my answer, you shouldn't be versioning that package at all since SDK v2.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is this line of your `csproj`:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.*" />
```

The `*` is saying to pick the latest 2.1 version of that NuGet package. For many packages, this would be perfectly fine. However, v2.1.1 of that package requires a matching v2.1.1 SDK to also be installed. As of right now, it is not available ([it's currently blocked](https://twitter.com/DamianEdwards/status/1009137684898435073)).

However, if you read the [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.0 to 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1) docs, you will see this:

> Replace the version specified "Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" package reference with the versionless "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" package reference.

The version is now inferred by the version of the SDK you are targeting. This means your `csproj` should now contain this:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

Comment: This does not work with me, I get Version Conflict errors which asked me to reference packages directly like Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies, etc. which eventually ended in a cycling reference error with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal requiring Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation first and vice versa.

Answer (score 8):

The 2.1.1 (preview) SDK is available on their GitHub.

You can download directly here:

https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/orchestrated-release-2-1/20180605-09/final/assets/Sdk/2.1.301-preview-008906/dotnet-sdk-2.1.301-win-x64.exe

See:

https://github.com/dotnet/versions/tree/7a833dddfddc27f2074b755b94234a25b9757637/build-info/dotnet/product/cli/release/2.1

We are still waiting on the official SDK...

**Edit:**

If you are having trouble building, add the following to your `.csproj`

```
<PropertyGroup>     
  <TargetLatestAspNetCoreRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestAspNetCoreRuntimePatch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Update:**

Official 2.1.1 SDK now released: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.1.301-windows-x64-installer

Comment: No, that is a **preview** release only. The final release is not yet available. It is stuck in publishing for some technical reason. Do not install this on a production machine!

Comment: I've given a more complete answer to this problem that will work for all future releases.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other suggestions, I needed to up the Microsoft.NetCore.App to 2.1.1.  Since I couldn't do it via the UI, adding the following to the .csproj worked.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
```

Comment: No, don't do this please. For v2.1 and above you no longer specify a version number for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, it is automatically done for you.

Comment: This is NOT true.  Currently, without specifying a version, it pulls 2.1.0.  IF you want to pull 2.1.1, you MUST specify the version.  I've verified this on 10+ projects so far.  This may change in the very near future, but today, it is the case.  Please verify before you downvote.

Comment: Read the docs, you don't need to specify the version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: The docs are wrong.  I've definitively, and repeatedly proven that only specifying the version 2.1.1 works.  Removing the version does 2.1.0 only.  I've done this a dozen times now,  Docs<evidence.

Comment: And are you also running the 2.1.1 SDK? I have also confirmed this works fine. So forgive me if I trust my eyes and the docs rather than you.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what "works fine"?  I'd love to see it for myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Another option is, in NuGet Package Manager, rollback Microsoft.AspNetCore.All, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite, and Microsoft.NETCore.App to versions 2.1.0.

Answer (score -1):

The wildcard version number package references is weird to me. That doesn't happen by default, so either you or one of your team members did that. I don't know if that's the source of at least some of your issues or not, but I'd start by changing them to full version references. NuGet packages are not committed with your project, so having wildcards can lead to strange build issues, particularly in automated builds, when you're developing against one version but a different version is restored later. If you want to upgrade a package, that should be an explicit choice, so you can then verify that all your code still functions as it should post-upgrade.

Also worth noting, since 2.1, code generation has been rolled in, so you should not be explicitly referencing any CodeGen packages.

As far as solving the current issue goes. You may be having some issues with your package cache. In Visual Studio, go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Management Settings, and then click the "Clear All NuGet Cache(s)" button.

That should prompt a redownload of all your projects NuGet packages, and may be enough to solve the issue. If not, I'd recommend cleaning all your projects and then going into the directory for each and manually deleting both the `bin` and `obj` directories. Then, rebuild your solution.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/287).

Comment: using wild card for the last segment has been working fine for me for a long time. I ship a bunch of open source nugets and I ship a VS project template that wires them up that way so I don't need to ship a new project template every time I ship a minor update to the nugets. I tried pinning to specific packages with 2..1.1 but still no joy. Maybe pinning to 2.1.0 would work but soemthing is wrong with the 2.1.1 package release.

Comment: @khellang: Damn Microsoft. They literally *just* switched everyone to `All` from `App`, and now they're apparently switching back to `App`. Be aware, though, that `App` is a more limited metapackage, so you may need to manually reference some additional packages after making the switch. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Well, wildcards may work most of the time, sure - especially, if you're only wildcarding the patch number. Still, it's a bad idea to do so, since even a patch can break things.

Comment: if the design packages are all baked in why did they ship a version 2.1.0 and 2.1.1 of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design ?

Comment: Well, they probably mean that it's included in the metapackage now. I just know that having an explicit codegen reference has borked both my own and other users here on StackOverflow projects. It probably just has the potential to lead to version inconsistencies.

Comment: Note that for v2.1 and above you no longer specify a version number for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, it is automatically done for you.

Answer (score -1):

For bugged SDK 2.1.301 version use:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" **Version="2.1.0"** />
and force all other packages 2.1.1 -> 2.1.0.

Comment: No, don't do this please. For v2.1 and above you no longer specify a version number for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, it is automatically done for you.

Comment: SDK 2.1.301 is broken. This was the only (but temporary) way to repair references. It works

Comment: What makes you say it's broken?

Comment: SDK 2.1.301 does not allow to install Microsoft.NETCore.App in 2.1.1 (version blocked by project), but it forces Microsoft.AspNetCore.App in 2.1.1 version. When you try to run project it crashes while debuging with output error "The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.1' was not found"

Comment: Then you are doing something terribly wrong. That's not a .NET bug, it's an issue with your project. However, if you genuinely believe you have a problem, you should report it as an issue on the Github repo.

Comment: DavidG - you are right. I have added <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion> It works with 2.1.1 packages now.

Answer (score -1):

Installing 2.1.301 (https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.1.1-download.md) fixed this issue for me.

Comment: How does this add to existing answers at all?